# how to access character pointer value using ctypes?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a written a DLL in which I'm getting one of the paths:

```
//demo.h
__declspec(dllexport) void pathinfo(char * path);
```

Something is being done in the code to get this path.
And now, the python script that I have written to retrieve this path from the DLL is as shown:

```
//demo.py
import sys 
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
class demo(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.demoDLL=CDLL("demo.dll")

  def pathinfo(self):
     path=c_char()
     self.demoDLL.pathinfo.argtypes(POINTER(c_char))
     self.demoDLL.pathinfo.result=None
     self.demoDLL.pathinfo(byref(path))
     return path.value

if __name__=='__main__':
    abc=demo()
    path_info=abc.pathinfo()
    print "information of the path:",path_info
```

But the value that I'm able to see is just the first character of the path instead of the whole string.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see only the first character is that by calling `c_char()` you create a single `char` value that Python treats like a `str` (Python 2) object or `bytes` (Python 3) object of length 1. You are probably lucky that you do not get a segmentation fault. By writing more than 1 byte or a NULL-terminated string of length > 0 (e.g. with `strcpy`) in the C code, you actually produce an undetected buffer overflow. `ctypes` does not know how many bytes you have written at the pointer's memory location. `path.value` is still a `str` / `bytes` of length 1.

It would be better to change the C `pathinfo` function into someting like

```
size_t pathinfo(char* path, size_t bsize);
```

Use `ctypes.create_string_buffer()` to allocate memory in your Python code and let `pathinfo` return the length of the result. Of course you have to check, whether `char* path` is large enough using `bsize` in your C-Code.

The Python-code would look like this:

```
buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(256)
result_len = pathinfo(buf, len(buf))
if result_len == len(buf):
    # buffer may have been too short,
    # try again with larger buffer
    ...
restlt_str = buf[0:result_len].decode('utf-8') # or another encoding
```

Also be aware of NULL-termination in the C domain, character encodings when converting python strings to `char*` and back, the changes regarding `str` / `bytes` in `ctypes` regarding Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done it, but have done the following:

To pass an array of `ints`, for example, use this:

Create a type of, say, 20 ints:

```
Ints20 = c_int * 20
```

Create an instance:

```
data = Ints20()
```

And then you can pass `data`.
Extract the numbers from `data` by using the `list` function:

```
values = list(data)
```

So may be you can do the same with chars:

```
Chars20 = c_char * 20
path = Chars20()
```

and then:

```
self.demoDLL.pathinfo(path)
```

In the case of c_char array there is no need to use the `list` function, but this works:

```
return path.value
```